# Is memory use restricted in python threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, memory

Python 2.7.  I have a GUI written with Tkinter that creates a separate thread to run a task so that the GUI is not blocked while it runs.  There is no locking implemented anywhere:

```py
class MainWindow(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        # Configure the window, buttons etc

    def button_function(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.myfunction)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        return

    def myfunction(self);
        # Calls a function in an imported module
```

When I run this the GUI hangs, and then crashes without traceback.  It does not crash if I call the function in the main thread (although the GUI does 'freeze' while myfunction is running):

```py
    def button_function(self):
        self.myfunction()   # Runs fine
        return
```

The function itself can sometimes store several MB in memory while running.  Commenting out the larger variables allows the function to return successfully.

I should add that the child thread makes no calls to GUI functions.  The GUI is just a wrapper around a separate command line function.

I suspect the correct solution would be to either write out larger variables into temporary files, or re-architect the function to return to the main thread more often.

Is there a restriction on memory usage in child threads, and if so, how is this configured?

Comment: There's no memory limit in child threads. Crash without traceback smells environmental issue, rather than python internals. Where are you running your code? Which OS, laptop/server, etc etc?

Comment: @favoretti Excellent suggestion, thanks!  I was running on a Windows 10 laptop.  Your response prompted me to try this on a Linux VM, and while I didn't quite get the same problem, it did flag up that the threaded function was calling pyplot.close(), which needs to be run in the main thread (https://github.com/idlespork/idlespork/issues/8).  If you want to answer with 'There's no memory limit in child threads' I will mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: that's ok, I see someone else already added that answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no memory limit in child threads.

(I encourage favoretti or mcy to post a similar answer for acceptance, so this doesn't join the infinite queue of unanswered questions. There's nothing wrong with OP answering his own question.)

Comment: Yours is good enough!  It looks like my problem is a PyInstaller issue rather than the GUI or threading.  I'll post another question / answer once I get it figured out.